# $\cot(2\cot^{-1}t)$ simplifies to?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cot(2\cot^{-1}t)$$

A. $\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{2}$

B. $\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{2t}$

C. $t-\frac{1}{2t}$

D. $t-\frac{1}{t}$

E. $t^2-\frac{2}{t^2}$

I'm not sure how to express $\cot^{-1}t$, so I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A substitution (almost) always helps. Put $t = \cot \theta$. Then, 
$$
\cot(2 \cot^{-1} t)=\cot (2 \theta) = \frac{1}{\tan 2\theta} = \frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{2 \tan \theta} = \frac{\cot \theta}{2} - \frac{1}{2 \cot \theta} = \frac t2 - \frac{1}{2t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to.

Hints:

$$\cot 2x=\frac1{\tan 2x}=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{2\tan x}$$

$$\tan(\cot^{-1}t)=\frac1{\cot\cot^{-1}t}=\frac1t$$